# TextView with autoSizeText wont work correctly when resizing multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-textview-autosize

I'm having a hard time figuring out the problem with autoSizeText used in TextView.

Info: I have an activity that will show app tips to the user. Tips will automatically change every n seconds. The problem I have is with TextView (android:id="@+id/tipDescription") that has autoSizeText.

The default textSize is 30sp, maxTextSize is also 30sp, and minTextSize is 10sp.

When the TextView with autoSizeText sets text with a lot of characters, the textSize will reduce which is great. The problem occurs when the textSize stays the same (small) even when the text in TextView is back to normal lengths that fit the View.

**Example:**

Text 1: "Start text" - textSize is 30sp

Text 2: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s." - textSize is reduced accordingly.

Text 3: "End text" - textSize is now the same as with Text 2, which is too small.

I am looking for a solution that will reset the textSize (back to 30sp) when the text is back to normal length.

**XML (activity_main.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:background="#444"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tipTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TITLE"
                android:textColor="#FF00FF"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tipSubtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SUBTITLE"
                android:textColor="#80FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tipDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="Start text"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="30sp"
                app:autoSizeMinTextSize="10sp"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java (MainActivity.java)**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tipDescription = findViewById(R.id.tipDescription);

        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> tipDescription.setText("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s."), 2000);
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> tipDescription.setText("End text"), 4000);
    }
}
```

I have already tried **tipDescription.setTextSize** but it's not working with autoSizeText enabled.

I'm using **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** to keep everything vertically centered in parent LinearLayout (tipSubtitle below tipTitle and tipDescription below tipSubtitle).

Comment: To make `AutoSize` works this way you need to fix size of textView right now its wrap_content. Try adding a fix Height to `TextView`  and then check .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Fixed layout height works. The reason I'm using android:layout_height="wrap_content" is to keep everything vertically centered in parent LinearLayout (tipSubtitle below tipTitle and tipDescription below tipSubtitle).

Comment: You can not have it both ways Auto sizing depends on the Size of View . You have to fix the Height Either make it  match constraints or make the height fixed.

Comment: @ADM Thank you! I'll have to find an alternative design.